# Wifi Reboot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless

this is my first time using ubuntu, I have big problems connecting to the wi fi, once I connect it work all right for minutes then it become real slow until i can no longer connect, but once I reboot the same process repeats, I have ubuntu 14.04LTS, can updating it to 15.04LTS solve the problem ?, any suggestion or wacky codes that can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the terminal window using this command:
CTRL + ALT + T
Then, you need to type in the following command:

sudo service network-manager restart

OR

sudo service NetworkManager restart

This way, you are restarting the connection instead of restarting the whole machine.

Comment: Didn't work ! :(